# Azure Mobile SDK fails to resolve Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've installed the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client nuget package installed with the latest version(3.1.0).
All dependencies were resolved correctly but I've got the error posted below.
In nuget I can't see any 6.0.0.0 version. Also the Mobile nuget package itself requires a minimum of 6.0.4, so I've installed 6.0.4 but I still got the error below.
Does anyone has any idea?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
```

stacktrace:

```
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.GetApplicationInstallationId()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor(Uri mobileAppUri, HttpMessageHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor(String mobileAppUri, HttpMessageHandler[] handlers)
```

Comment: The error is because your program can't find Newtonsoft.Json - not sure why, but it sounds like a VIsual Studio install issue?

Comment: seems like this was just the first part. after a complete restart of the whole system, the error is solved. but all in all, the whole thing is quite buggy. Some builds fail, some not.